# How to use the dart_vlc package for desktop application in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am building an application for desktop using flutter. I want to show some videos on it but the packages referred by the flutter team does not supports desktop. So, i am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_vlc) package to serve the purpose.

But i am unable to load videos to my app using this because whenever i try to use player.open(as given in the api documentation), it gives an error. Can anyone please help me to run the videos using this package ?

Comment: Have you tried running their program which they have given on Github? If the same problem occurs please show your error or logcat window.

Comment: They have not given any video file in the example. That's just UI.